# Toggling div visibility onClick in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to toggle the display of this div on

click, but it's not working and I've been stuck for a minute. Any suggestions?

[image: img1]
[image: imge2]

Comment: Please add code not photos.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Code relevant to your problem belongs directly to your question, in text form and properly formatted.

Comment: Please paste your code in snippet

Answer (score 0):

use `onClick={()=>this.generateSSO(min,max)}` instead of `onClick={this.generateSSO(min,max)}`